# vscode: how to have copy filename in the right click context menu in file explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio

In the  explorer, how can I have option to copy filename

There is no option to copy filename when I right click on a file in explorer

The below image shows what I meant

[image]

Comment: search or write an extension that adds this command

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Context Menu Extra](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.context-menu-extra) v0.2.0

I have added the context command `Copy File Name`